# How Can I get Steam id And Then Get Steam Username?

Tags: c++, game-engine, steam, steamworks-api

Hi All So I was Studying Steam API, And Now I want to Get The Steam id And User name Using Steam API (64bit)
First I've read this on Steam Website: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamFriends#GetPersonaName
And Then it Didn't Work So I Searched More And Then Found This:
[Steam API getting persona name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333460/steam-api-getting-persona-name)
this didn't work again and has a compile error: **E0140 too many arguments in function call**.
Then I found this:
[How to retrieve Steam username using SteamWorks API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35281019/how-to-retrieve-steam-username-using-steamworks-api)
even this didn't work again and when I run my project Visual Studio Says:[The Visual Studio Error in Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFroy.png)
So now I don't know What to do Please Help Me

```cpp
    CSteamID id = SteamUser()->GetSteamID();
    const char* pchName = SteamFriends()->GetPersonaName(id);
    std::cout << SteamFriends()->GetPersonaName();
    std::cout << pchName;
```

Comment: As the API says, `GetPersonaName` doesn't take any parameters. The documentiona also states "To get the persona name of other users use GetFriendPersonaName." maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Here you go Take a look 
it's doesn't work again
```c++
    CSteamID id = SteamUser()->GetSteamID();
    const char* pchName = SteamFriends()->GetFriendPersonaName(id);
    std::cout << pchName;
```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J2JxfEHlohZugwnWyw5RDLHQ7asGrcs6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also as you can see SteamUser() returns nullptr 
which means there's something wrong with Steam App or API
But I've Logged in to My Steam Account Already and My Steam is Opened

Comment: Did you successfully initialize the API?

Comment: yeah 
for ensure can you do it for me in a visual studio proejct and then send that over and i'll try again

Comment: Sure. Where do I send the bill, and do you prefer to pay in Bitcoin or U.S. dollars?

Comment: oh sorry i thought you wanted to help me

Answer (score 0):

Use GetPersonaName() call without parameter 'id'.

```
const char* pchName = SteamFriends()->GetPersonaName();
```

Comment: It doesn't work again 
Can you Do a Visual Studio Project Template With Steam64 API + With This Code ?

Comment: it returns a nullptr

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am not using Visual Studio ...
But this C++ code works great in both Linux and Windows:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <chrono>
    #include <thread>
    #include <fstream>
    
    #include <steam_api.h>
    
    void close_steam() {
        SteamAPI_Shutdown();
    }
    
    void program() {
        if (!SteamAPI_Init() ) {
            std::cerr << "Steam's API could not be initialized!\n";
            std::cerr << "Ensure that Steam is running on the same user account...\n";
            std::exit(1);
        }
    
        atexit(close_steam);
    }
    
    int main() {
        program();
        const char* pchName = SteamFriends()->GetPersonaName();
        std::cout << pchName;
    }
```